# Jest mockResolvedValueOnce/mockReturnValueOnce access function parameter

Tags: jestjs

I want to write a mock function that will return different values at each call. The problem I have is that the returned value is depends on the parameter value passed to the function.

```
//something like this
window.fetch = jest.fn(urlPath)
                   .mockResolvedValueOnce(fetch({urlPath}))
                   .mockResolvedValueOnce(fetch({urlPath, arg1: 1}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this, maybe help [jest-when](https://github.com/timkindberg/jest-when), not sure it works

```
import { when } from 'jest-when';

window.fetch = jest.fn(urlPath);
when(window.fetch).calledWith({urlPath, arg1: 1}).mockReturnValue('test');
await expect(window.fetch({urlPath, arg1: 1})).resolves.toEqual('test')
```

Comment: I want mockReturnValue to have access to the parameters like arg1

Comment: why do mockReturnValue need to have access to the parameters? you can pass arg1 
 directly to mockReturnValue

Comment: How do I pass arg1, urlPath to mockReturnValue?

Comment: as I understand `when(window.fetch).calledWith({'/api/v1/...,' arg1: 1}).mockReturnValue('/api/v1/.....')`

Answer (score 1):

Use a mock implementation. It allows you to pass a function and handle it in a granular way.

`jest.mockImplementation((arg1, arg2) => return whatever(arg1, arg2))`